# How to change the alertcontroller textfield keyboard to numberpad?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

Given below is the code for my alertcontroller
I want to make numberpad appear instead of normal keyboard when I type in the textfield.how to do this??

```
func addPasscodeAlert()
{
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .Light)
    let blurVisualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurVisualEffectView.frame = view.bounds
    self.view.addSubview(blurVisualEffectView)

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "No passcode saved", message: "Please enter new 4 digit passcode.", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel) { (action) -> Void in


        if let textField = alertController.textFields?.first as UITextField?
        {
            textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
            self.passcode = textField.text!
            let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            userDefaults.setObject(self.passcode, forKey: "passcode")
            self.showPasswordAlert()
        }
    }

    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

    alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) -> Void in

        textField.placeholder = "Password"
        textField.secureTextEntry = true
    }
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    blurVisualEffectView.removeFromSuperview()


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change keyboard type in handler method not in `UIAlertAction`.
replace your code with below.

```
alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) -> Void in
    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
    textField.placeholder = "Password"
    textField.secureTextEntry = true
}
```